# hive group by contain repeat result

Tags: hadoop, hive

my hql is:

```
select day,app_id,platform,count(1) as dau from (select ad.day,ads.app_id,ads.platform,ad.deviceid from mobile_ad_space ads inner join (select day,deviceid,flightid from mobile_day_adlog where day='$STAT_DAY') ad on cast(ads.space_id as string)=ad.flightid   group by ad.day,ads.app_id,ads.platform,ad.deviceid) day_active group by day,app_id,platform having dau>5;
```

but the result contains repeat data:

```
| day        | appid | platform | dau|

| 2016-06-29 |   1 | ios      | 70533 |

| 2016-06-29 |   1 | android  | 49307 |

| 2016-06-29 |   1 | android  | 49307 |

| 2016-06-29 |   1 | android  | 49307 |
```

I have also tried other hql :

```
SELECT day_active.day  ,day_active.app_id  ,day_active.platform  ,count(1) AS dau FROM (  SELECT day_device.day AS day   ,day_device.app_id AS app_id   ,day_device.platform AS platform   ,day_device.deviceid AS deviceid  FROM     (SELECT ad.day AS day   ,ads.app_id AS app_id   ,ads.platform AS platform   ,ad.deviceid AS deviceid  FROM mobile_ad_space ads  INNER JOIN (   SELECT day    ,deviceid    ,flightid   FROM mobile_day_adlog   WHERE day = '$STAT_DAY'   ) ad ON cast(ads.space_id AS string) = ad.flightid) day_device                GROUP BY day_device.day   ,day_device.app_id   ,day_device.platform   ,day_device.deviceid  ) day_active GROUP BY day_active.day  ,day_active.app_id  ,day_active.platform HAVING dau>5 ORDER BY day_active.day  ,day_active.app_id  ,day_active.platform;
```

but it still have this problem

is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Have you checked spaces? Try to use trim(platform) as platform...group by trim(platform), repeat for other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I found a solution.

In my HQL,I use `insert overwrite directory '$HQL_OUT_PATH'` to overwrite the output.But It seems to be unstable which result in repeat items.Thus, I clean the output path before the HQL and the result turn out tobe right now~!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check whether values contain spaces, use trim() in group by. Also check how many distinct values there are for each group by column: `select distinct platform ...` and so on

Comment: good point! But it still does not work.I trim  platform from the beginning :SELECT ad.day AS day   ,ads.app_id AS app_id   ,trim(ads.platform) AS platform   ,ad.deviceid AS deviceid  FROM mobile_ad_space ads

Comment: The interesting thing is the repeat row has also the same count,which seems indicate something